# R: How to make the colon operator behave like in Python numpy for slicing "until the end"?

Tags: r, operator-overloading

In Python `numpy`, you can refer to the last (say 2) elements of an `array` using the colon operator, without explicitly stating you are "slicing until the end location", like this:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(range(5))
arr[3:]
```

or

```
arr[-2:]
```

In R, with a simple vector, you either have the `tail` function:

```
arr = 0:4
tail(arr, 2)
```

Or you can slice the vector using the colon operator but have to specify the "end location", like this:

```
arr[4:length(arr)]
```

Is there a way to make R's colon operator behave the same way as in Python `numpy` arrays? To overload it somehow. At least for the last case where you want `arr[4:]` to slice the vector for the last two locations, 4 and 5.

Comment: Note that head and tail work for matrices as well: (mat <- matrix(1:20,nrow=4)); 
head(mat,2);
tail(mat,2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `arr[3:]` because the parser won't let you.

You could do it this way (trigger warning, that'll be ugly) :

We'll overload `'['` and modify the arguments to replace `:Inf` by the relevant dimension of the input. It is NOT a general solution (though it's possible to build one), and it will slow down everything.

It also doesn't work as it is with nested brackets such as `test_array[1:8[2:Inf]]`.

```
`[` <- function(a,...){ 
  ellipsis <- as.character(substitute(list(...)));
  if(length(ellipsis) == 2){
    base::'['(a, eval(parse(text=gsub(":Inf",paste0(":",length(a)),ellipsis[[2]]))))
              } else {
      base::'['(a, eval(parse(text=gsub(":Inf",paste0(":",nrow(a)),ellipsis[[2]]))),
                eval(parse(text=gsub(":Inf",paste0(":",ncol(a)),ellipsis[[3]]))))
  }
}

test_array <- 1:10
test_matrix <- matrix(1:16,ncol=4)

test_array[5:Inf]
# [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10

test_matrix[3:Inf,2:Inf]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    7   11   15
# [2,]    8   12   16
```

Note that you can also do `arr[-(1:3)]` instead of `arr[4:length(arr)]`

Comment: Nice. Be careful what you wish for, eh?

Comment: Indeed, maybe the line I added at the end of my post will be more practical for you :)